# Disable Active Directory Inactive Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server

In my organization, there are many user accounts whose users were laid off. Unfortunately, there is no way I can get the username of them from Human Resource. The thing comes to my mind is to check each users last logon attributes and disable the users that were logged in long time ago. But, I have over 1000 users. It takes forever to do so. Is there any command or third party that I can use? Honestly, I am newbie. So, I am not really familiar with cmd or PowerShell jargon.

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Inactive-User-in-78b8db79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Windows Server 2012, you can do certain search using Active Directory Administration Center.

Otherwise, you can use third parties which I have tested before:
[Borna AD manager](http://www.danapardaz.net/site/en/borna-active-directory-management), [AD manager plus](https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/) and OLDCMP all satisfy your need.

Comment: Cool tools. But it seems they are not free.

Comment: Use their trial version. At least it works for now! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Run the below in PS ISE . This will give the details for the last *30 days*.

Make sure you have the **ActiveDirectory Module**. By default it will be there in the AD if you are running from there .

```
import-module activedirectory ;
$domain_name = "mydomain.com" ;
$file = "User.csv" ;
$Days = 30 ;
Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt ((Get-Date).Adddays(-($Days))) -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp | select-object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} | export-csv $file -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thanks. How can i possibly disable them all? the output file contains over 250 usernames.

Comment: Instead of doing Out-File , you can pipe it **Disable-ADAccount**.. 

Usage you can check it in [Disable-ADAccount](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617197.aspx)